# Make getters and setters function in phpDesigner8

Tags: php, ide, phpdesigner

Hi i need to make getters and setter in phpDesigner8 like in Zend Studio.
My office computer is not very  powerful for Zend 8 or 9.
(Please don't write "change the IDE" I like this one).

Anybody knows is it possible or not ?

```
class A 
{
   protected $x;
   protected $y;

   public function getX()  // I need this automatically.
   {
     //....
   }

   public function setX($x)  // I need this automatically.
   {
          //......
   }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: php built in overloaders __get and __set methods http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set, I like zend too

Comment: Thanks  Lawrence. But I need phpDesigner  to do that.
I mean not __get , __set or __call it's php functions and here I need
to press button(buttons) and phpDesigner will generate the code for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is imposible to make automatic getters and setters with phpDesigner8!

Comment: so then, what is the alternative of phpDesigner of making set & get more faster? @elo

Answer (score 1):

I was exactly at the same situation, and still haven't found any macro functionallity in phpDesigner.

So just decided to use Autohotkey. It is a very small free program (it will suit your old computer needs) that has a very powerfull scripting language for building macros.

- http://www.autohotkey.com/download

This way, this method can be applied across any IDE you use, not only PhpDesigner.

I have written the following script:

```
^t::   ;invoke by copying variable name to clipboard, and pressing control+t
  fun = %ClipBoard%           ;takes the content of clipboard
  result = `r`n/**            ;`r`n = carriage return on windows
  result = %result% `r`n * @return
  result = %result% `r`n */
  result = %result% `r`npublic function get_%fun%() {
  result = %result% `r`n`treturn $this->%fun%;
  result = %result% `r`n`}`r`n
  result = %result% `r`n/** 
  result = %result% `r`n * @param %fun%
  result = %result% `r`n * @return
  result = %result% `r`n */ 
  result = %result% `r`npublic function &set_%fun%($%fun%) {
  result = %result% `r`n`t$this->%fun% = $%fun%;
  result = %result% `r`n`treturn $this;
  result = %result% `r`n`}
  result = %result% `r`n
  ClipBoard = %result%        ;stores result on clipboard
  Send {down}{home}           ;moves to prevent overwriting selected text
  Send ^v                     ;writes result to text editor
  Send {shiftdown}{controldown}{f1}{controlup}{shiftup} ;PHPDesigner format file
  Sleep 50                    ;waits for paste to finish                    
  ClipBoard = %fun%           ;restores previous clipboard          
  VarSetCapacity(fun, 0)      ;empties variable     
Return
```

It works this way: first look for a property definition (or write it down):

```
protected $table_name_a;
```

Then, select "table_name_a", copy it to the clipboard (control+c), then press control+t.
When doing so, it writes down (and calls Control+Shitf+F1 to format code in current file):

```
/**
 * @return 
 */
public function get_table_name_a() {
    return $this->table_name_a;
}

/**
 * @param table_name_a 
 * @return 
 */
public function &set_table_name_a($table_name_a) {
    $this->table_name_a = $table_name_a;
    return $this;
}
```

The code produced is designed to suit my needs. I still have to code inside comments and function calls, types and classes for variables, for documenting and type hinting purposes.

You can easily modify the script, for example, prompting for variable name, so its declaration is written also (I happen to have all protected variables already coded).

Internet is full of documentation, examples and help on Autohotkey, you can start at:

- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm